# How do I solve this Implementation() error?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm getting an error whenever I run the implementation() method.

I tried to import this Insiteo '.aar' file and set it's dependencies, but there's an issue with calling 'implementation()' method. Help?

Insiteo module build.gradle:

```
configurations.maybeCreate("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('Insiteo-SDK-3.6.3g.aar'))


dependencies {
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
}
```

Here's the error

```
Error:(6, 0) Could not find method implementation() for arguments ['com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2']
```

App module build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.joey.projectgenesis"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    implementation project(':Insiteo')
}
```

Project build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My Android plugin version is 3.0.1, and my Gradle version is 4.4.1

I've also tried `compile()` as well with the same error.

There isn't any problems with the other `build.gradle` scripts, just the Insiteo module script, and it's only with the `implementation()` method.

Comment: What is the directory structure of your project? Is Insiteo something you wrote or is it a third-party library?

Comment: I edited it. Insiteo is third-party.

Comment: Are you trying to add dependencies to Insiteo?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't add dependencies to an aar module like that. You most likely need to apply the app or library plugin in order to do that.

But it's generally easier just adding the dependencies directly into your project; not into the library module. Example:

```
Root /
    app/
    myAarLibrary/
```

Don't define dependencies in `myAarLibrary`, define them in `app`

Answer (score 1):

Your gradle have some problem. You can use `compile` instead `implelentaion` in gradle dependencies. All gradle support this by default.

Comment: `compile` is now deprecated in Android Studio 3.0 & above

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you are using Android Studio 3.0 or above.
2. Your `app` level `build.gradle` should look like this:

   ```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

   buildscript {

       repositories {
           google()
           jcenter()
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

           // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
           // in the individual module build.gradle files
       }
   }

   allprojects {
       repositories {
           google()
           jcenter()
       }
   }

   task clean(type: Delete) {
       delete rootProject.buildDir
   }
   ```
3. Make sure your `gradle-wrapper.properties` looks like this:

   ```
   #DATE
   distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
   distributionPath=wrapper/dists
   zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
   zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
   ```

Use

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

instead of

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
```